# what is jqgrid required html element

Tags: jqgrid

Most of the examples that are provided in jqgrid documentation starts off with table tag with an id. Can we create/initialize the grid with say div or any other html tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick glimpse into *jqGrid* source code will reveal following snippet:

```
if(this.tagName.toUpperCase()!='TABLE') {
    alert("Element is not a table");
    return;
}
```

So the element must be a table.

There is no explicit check for `id` attribute, but it is used in several places for building the surrounding elements so you should keep it as well.